# Exact VLOOKUPs are not acting the same

Tags: excel

I have this lookup that I'm doing that is giving me fits today.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ONE",(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E3,'Membership'!$A$2:$S$6500,19,FALSE),"N")))), "ONE", "N")

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TWO",(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E3,'Membership'!$A$2:$S$6500,19,FALSE),"N")))), "TWO", "N")
```

Membership column 19, is a number concatenated to text: 1 ONE; 2 TWO; 3 ONE/

It's working for ONE but not TWO. Actually, I have seven and it's working for two and not the other five.

I must be too close to the trees.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated!

Please let me know if any additional info is needed.

Comment: The VLOOKUP is searching in the A column. What kind of values are in column A?

Comment: you are looking for E3 and if it is not found (error) then you return "N" and search it for "ONE" which doesnt make sense at all to me... wouldn't do `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ONE",VLOOKUP($E3,'Membership'!$A$2:$S$6500,19,FALSE))), "ONE", "N")` the same?

Comment: @dev1998, col should be numeric and that might be the problem. I noticed that half of column was set to text. The problem appears to be solved after changing the entire col to numeric. Though I've booted out of my office and must go home to test. I'll provide an update after testing.

Comment: @Dirk: yes, that's probably better. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Dirk, Now that I'm off mobile I see that a part of the code was missing the part that you added: , "ONE", "N")

Comment: @veblen i just skipped the `IFERROR(... ,"N")` cus it should not do a difference... so right now, I don't get your last comment O.o

Comment: @Dirk, it looks like I had left the "ONE", or "TWO", off of my sample lines at the end. You're correct on the IFERROR, so I'll remove them. THANKS! 

I just want to find out how a column of data reverted back to text from numeric. That is source of my "fun."